# Why Are These Conditional Operators Used in This JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, conditional-statements

I was reading a web site's page source code when I found these two lines:

```
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
```

What is the significance of the conditional `||` operator when assigning the variables' values? I don't understand why `||` would be used with an empty object or an empty array, and to what purpose it serves.

Comment: If you look up `||` in the manual it will become evident. Or just play a bit with it in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it like this:

```
var my_var = false || 34;
alert(my_var); //what do you see?
```

If the previous condition is true, that will be assigned to `my_var`. Otherwise, it will be the second condition.

In this way, one is able to guarantee that they have an object they can work with with the rest of the script. Python, for example, will do this when chaining `dict.get()` calls to ensure that it doesn't blow up. In this instance, if we need to search a dict for another dict and then search *that* for a second key, we can do so like this (as an example):

```
found_value = one_dict.get(first_key, {}).get(second_key, False)
```

In this way, we guarantee that if `first_key` doesn't exist in the dict, we at least get an empty `dict` so that the second `.get()` call isn't called on the wrong object.

Answer (score 1):

When you evaluate an expression of the form x || y, the result will be x, if x evaluates to true when converted to a boolean. Otherwise the result will be y.

Generally this is used as quick shortcut to say: if x has a value, return x; otherwise return y as a default. Of course, "has a value" is a little vague. If the value of x is something with a boolean value of false, like **false** or **0**, you'll get y, even if you wanted x. So you have to be careful when using this sort of expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shortcut for saying

if googletag isn't undefined use googletag else create a new empty object

Answer (score 0):

It's the difference between assigning `undefined`, which could cause all sort of problems, and the valid Empty Object `{}` and Empty Array `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

This will assign `googletag` (for example) to itself or create new one.

For example in case if `googletag` has value, `googletag` will be that value, else empty object